# How to sort a HashMap in descending order (based on the value) and keep the lexigraphy order (based on key) at the same time?

Tags: java

The code below can get the descending order based on value, but I have no idea of how to keep the lexigraphy order.

If two elements have the same value, e.g. `hello-3` and `hi-3`,
then `hello-3` should in front of `hi-3` since `e` is in the front of `i`.

```
//get the descending order based on value (frequency)

public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> 
sortByValue( Map<K, V> map ) {
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
    new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>( map.entrySet() );

    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2 ) {
            // it should be o2 compareTo o1, since I need descending order
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
        }
    });

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list) {
        result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after sorting your first Map add this :

Map result = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

and then do this :

result .putAll(list);